# Using FILTER Function With Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am having issues using the Filter function in Google Spreadsheet. I am trying to get the following formula to work:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table!$C$2:C, AND(EXACT(Table!$A$2:A,A2)=TRUE, EXACT(Table!$B$2:B,B2)=TRUE))).
```

However it returns the error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 999. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1

I then tried the following formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table!$C$2:C, {EXACT(Table!$A$2:A,A2)=TRUE; EXACT(Table!$B$2:B,B2)=TRUE}))
```

And received the error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 999. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1998, column count: 1

---

Basically what I am trying to do is to add hours from another sheet ('Table') if and only if the hours are for a specific job and job type. I then try to display the total hours for a job and job type on another sheet ('Job Hours').

I am able to get this function to work:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table!$C$2:C, EXACT(Table!$A$2:A,A2)=TRUE))
```

But when I try to filter for a second condition, I get one of the errors above. Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried this function: =SUMIF(Table!$C$2:C, AND(EXACT(Table!$A$2:A,A2), EXACT(Table!$B$2:B,B2))=TRUE); but nothing got returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any of these formulas should deliver the expected outcome:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table!$C$2:C, Table!$A$2:A=A2, Table!$B$2:B=B2))
```

or:

```
=sumifs(Table!$C$2:C, Table!$A$2:A, A2, Table!$B$2:B, B2)
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( Table!$A$2:A=A2, Table!$B$2:B=B2, Table!$C$2:C)
```